# Use of "auto" in place of std::vector<double>*

Tags: c++

I am using a function like

```
void TestAnalyzer::AddBranch(std::vector<double>* vec, std::string name){
tree->Branch(name.c_str(),vec);
}
```

But in place of `vector<double>` sometimes I have int vectors also so how can I use "auto" or something else so that with the same argument it read int as well as double.

Comment: Provide overloads or use a function template.

Comment: Of course, you will need to do something similar to whatever `tree->Branch` is. And `auto` has little to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is a template. You will get a new, different function for each kind of vector.

```
template< typename element_type >
void TestAnalyzer::AddBranch(std::vector<element_type>* vec, std::string name){
tree->Branch(name.c_str(),vec);
}
```

`element_type` will be deduced from the function argument, just as `auto` is deduced from an initializer. This kind of usage is more primitive and works with C++98 (or many pre-standard compilers).

Comment: @ramkrishna: It's noteworthy that you might then want to make `tree->Branch` a template too.  Separately, name should almost certainly have been accepted by `const` reference for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a templated function.

```
template<typename T> void TestAnalyzer::AddBranch(std::vector<T>* vec, std::string name){
   tree->Branch(name.c_str(),vec);
}
```